# CurrentValueSubject send(value) doesn't trigger receiveValue

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a `CurrentValueSubject` to hold data received from `Firebase` fetch request.

```
final class CardRepository: ObservableObject {

    private let store = Firestore.firestore()
    var resultSubject = CurrentValueSubject<[Card], Error>([])
    init() {
    }
    
    func get() {
        store.collection(StorageCollection.EnglishCard.getPath)
            .addSnapshotListener { [unowned self] snapshot, err in
                if let err = err {
                    resultSubject.send(completion: .failure(err))
                }
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    let cards = snapshot.documents.compactMap {
                        try? $0.data(as: Card.self)
                    }
                    resultSubject.send(cards)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel, I want whenever `resultSubject` sends or `emits` a `value`. It will change the `state` and has that `value` attached to the `succes` state.

```
class CardViewModel: CardViewModelProtocol, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var repository: CardRepository
    @Published private(set) var state: CardViewModelState = .loading
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    required init (_ repository: CardRepository) {
        self.repository = repository
        bindingCards()
        
    }
    
    private func bindingCards() {
        let _ = repository.resultSubject
            .sink { [unowned self] comp in
                switch comp {
                case .failure(let err):
                    self.state = .failed(err: err)
                case .finished:
                    print("finised")
                }
            } receiveValue: { [unowned self] res in
                self.state = .success(cards: res)
            }

    }
    
    func add(_ card: Card) {
        repository.add(card)
    }
    
    func get() {
        repository.get()
    }

}
```

On my ContentView, it will display a button that `print` the `result`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = CardViewModel(CardRepository())
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .loading:
                ProgressView()
                Text("Loading")
            case .success(cards: let cards):
                let data = cards
                Button {
                    print(data)
                } label: {
                    Text("Tap to show cards")
                }
            case .failed(err: let err):
                Button {
                    print(err)
                } label: {
                    Text("Retry")
                }
            }
            Button {
                viewModel.get()
            } label: {
                Text("Retry")
            }
        }.onAppear {viewModel.get() }
    }
}
```

My problem is the block below only trigger once when I first bind it to the `resultSubject`.

```
} receiveValue: { [unowned self] res in
                self.state = .success(cards: res)
            }
```

I did add a debug and  `resultSubject.send(cards)` works every time.

Comment: We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI, you have to learn the View struct value type and the property wrappers that makes it behave like an object. If you use objects you'll just get the same consistency bugs it was designed to eliminate.

Comment: can you elaborate or link an article if possible please? I've been following SwiftUI tutorials and most of them use MVVM with an `viewModel` object (which will be injected at root or previous view, I just initialized it for faster testing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the `Cancellable` returned from the `.sink` in the class so it doesn't get deallocated:

Either in a set `var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()` if you want to use multiple `Publishers`, or in `var cancellable: AnyCancellable?`.

Add `.store(in &cancellables)` like so:

```
} receiveValue: { [unowned self] res in
    self.state = .success(cards: res)
}.store(in: &cancellables)
```

Edit:

In `ObservableObject` classes we don't use `sink`, we `assign` to an `@Published`:

```
let _ = repository.resultSubject
    .assign(to: &$self.state)
```

Comment: we don't use `sink` or cancellables in `ObservableObject`, we `assign` the end of the pipeline to `@Published` vars.